# Radon-Nikodym Derivative: Proposition 3.9 Folland

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, radon-nikodym

Suppose that $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite signed measure and $\mu, \lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite positive measures on $(X, \mathcal{M})$ such that $\nu \ll \mu$ and $\mu \ll \lambda$. Then, the following hold:

(a) If $g \in L^{1}(\nu),$ then $g(d \nu / d \mu) \in L^{1}(\mu)$ (the function $g$ multiplied by $d \nu / d \mu$) and
$$
\int g d \nu=\int g \frac{d \nu}{d \mu} d \mu
$$
(b) We have $\nu \ll \lambda$ (this is obvious from $\nu \ll \mu$ and $\mu \ll \lambda$), and
$$
\frac{d \nu}{d \lambda}=\frac{d \nu}{d \mu} \frac{d \mu}{d \lambda} \text{ holds for } \lambda \text {-a.e. }
$$

I have no qualms with the proof of (a). Here is the proof for (b), and I am having difficulty understanding the part in bold:

For any measurable set $E$, note that by definition we have
$$
\nu(E) = \int_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}\right)d\lambda.
$$
Use (a) by replacing measures $\nu,\mu$ by the measures $\mu, \lambda$, and we obtain that for $g \in L^1(\mu)$,
$$\int g d\mu = \int g \left(\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\right)d\lambda.$$
$\textbf{Letting $g = \chi_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)$, we obtain that (how do we show $g \in L^1(\mu)$? This is needed for us to use (a).)}$ $$\int \chi_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right) d\mu = \int \chi_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right) \left(\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\right)d\lambda.$$
We also have by definition:
$$
\nu(E) = \int_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)d\mu := \int \chi_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)d\mu.
$$
Thus, we conclude: $$\nu(E) = \int \chi_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right) d\mu = \int \chi_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right) \left(\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\right)d\lambda.$$
Note that we have shown $$
\nu(E) = \int_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}\right)d\lambda = \int \chi_E \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right) \left(\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\right)d\lambda.
$$
We can now apply proposition 1 to give the desired conclusion.

(This is irrelevant to the question, but) Proposition 1 states:

(a) If $f \in L^1$, then $\{ x:f(x) \neq 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite.

(b) If $f,g \in L^1$, then $\int_E f = \int_E g$ for all $E \in \mathcal{M}$ $\iff$ $\int ||f-g|| = 0$ $\iff$ $f = g$ a.e..

Comment: I guess the phrasing is somewhat poor, because you don't really need $g\in L^1(\nu)$ to apply $a)$. It suffices that $g$ is positive.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Really? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Just follows from the standard machinery. $\int \chi_E\textrm{d}\nu=\int \chi_E g\textrm{d}\mu$ by definition and by linearity, we get the identity for all simple functions. By monotone convergence, you get the identity for all positive $g$. We don't need the integrals to be finite for this.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou, ah yes. I just realized and was trying to edit my comment. However, why is $\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)$ positive? The Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem only states that $\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)$ is an extended $\mu$-integrable function, so it is measurable, and the range is in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah... my bad... we're of course working with signed measures. No... $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ is not a positive function.

Comment: However, $|\nu|=|\frac{d \nu}{d\mu}|d\mu$ (this is obvious from the Jordan-Hahn decomposition of $\nu$) and since $|\nu|$ is a finite, positive measure, we get $\frac{d \nu}{d\mu}\in L^1(\mu)$. Unless Folland allows for signed measures to attain one of the values $\pm \infty$, in which case you use $\sigma$-finiteness to reduce to the finite case.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou ok, let me work things out... And yes, Folland also allows for signed measures to take one of $\pm \infty$.

Comment: In that case, you'll only get $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\in L^1(\mu|_{E_n})$, where $E_n$ is a set such that $\nu$ is a bounded, signed measure on $E_n$.